# How do I calculate the coordinates of a triangle-ray intersection?

Tags: javascript, math, game-engine

So I'm writing my own game engine, and I recently wrote a triangle-ray intersector (and by wrote, I mean copied wholesale from [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330124410/http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html)). As of now, it runs through the whole function only if the ray and the triangle are intersecting, and while that's very helpful, I would like to know how to get the exact coordinates of the intersection. So what do you think the best way to go about this is?

I've prepared a Minimal Reproducible Example for the sake of experimentation:

```js
var cube = {
  "positions": [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0

  ],
  "indices": [
    0, 3, 2,
    1, 3, 0,

    3, 1, 7,
    1, 5, 7,

    0, 4, 5,
    5, 1, 0,

    6, 2, 7,
    2, 3, 7,

    5, 4, 7,
    7, 4, 6,

    0, 6, 4,
    0, 2, 6

  ],
  "uv": [
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,

    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,

    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,

    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
  ]
}

var camPos = [0, 0, -10];
var camRot = [0, 0, 0];

setInterval(() => {
  for (var j = 0; j < cube.indices.length; j += 3) {

    var startPos = [camPos[0], camPos[1], camPos[2]];
    var rotation = [-camRot[0], camRot[1], camRot[2]];
    var len = 1000000;

    var endPos = [
      startPos[0] + (len * Math.sin(rotation[1])),
      startPos[1] + (len * Math.tan(rotation[0])),
      startPos[2] + (len * Math.cos(rotation[1]))
    ];


    var dir = [
      endPos[0] - startPos[0],
      endPos[1] - startPos[1],
      endPos[2] - startPos[2],
    ];

    var v1 = [
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j] * 3],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j] * 3 + 1],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j] * 3 + 2]
    ];
    var v2 = [
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 1] * 3],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 1] * 3 + 1],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 1] * 3 + 2]
    ];
    var v3 = [
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 2] * 3],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 2] * 3 + 1],
      cube.positions[cube.indices[j + 2] * 3 + 2]
    ];

    var u = [
      v2[0] - v1[0],
      v2[1] - v1[1],
      v2[2] - v1[2]
    ];

    var v = [
      v3[0] - v1[0],
      v3[1] - v1[1],
      v3[2] - v1[2]
    ];

    var n = [
      u[1] * v[2] - u[2] * v[1],
      u[2] * v[0] - u[0] * v[2],
      u[0] * v[1] - u[1] * v[0]
    ];

    var w0 = [
      startPos[0] - v1[0],
      startPos[1] - v1[1],
      startPos[2] - v1[2]
    ];

    var a = -(n[0] * w0[0] + n[1] * w0[1] + n[2] * w0[2]);
    var b = (n[0] * dir[0] + n[1] * dir[1] + n[2] * dir[2]);

    if (b < 0) {
      continue;
    }

    /*if(Math.abs(b) < 0.00001){
        if(a==0){
            //console.log("parallel");
            continue;}
        else{
            //console.log("not intersecting");
            continue;}
    }*/

    var r = a / b;

    //console.log(r);

    if (r <= 0 || r >= 1) {
      //console.log("not intersecting");
      continue;
    }

    var rd = [
      dir[0] * r,
      dir[1] * r,
      dir[2] * r
    ];

    var ii = [
      startPos[0] + rd[0],
      startPos[1] + rd[1],
      startPos[2] + rd[2]
    ];

    var uu = u[0] * u[0] + u[1] * u[1] + u[2] * u[2];
    var uv = u[0] * v[0] + u[1] * v[1] + u[2] * v[2];
    var vv = v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2];

    var w = [
      ii[0] - v1[0],
      ii[1] - v1[1],
      ii[2] - v1[2]
    ];

    var wu = w[0] * u[0] + w[1] * u[1] + w[2] * u[2];
    var wv = w[0] * v[0] + w[1] * v[1] + w[2] * v[2];

    var d = uv * uv - uu * vv;

    var s = (uv * wv - vv * wu) / d;
    if (s <= 0 || s > 1) {
      //console.log("not intersecting");
      continue;
    }
    var t = (uv * wu - uu * wv) / d;

    if (t <= 0 || (s + t) > 1) {
      //console.log("not intersecting");
      continue;
    }

    // use these values to find the point of intersection somehow??
    console.log(s + "," + t + "," + (s + t));
  }
  camRot[1] = Math.sin(Date.now() / 1000) * .1;
}, 10);
```

My current hypothesis is that the best way to go about this would be to interpret it from the values returned when it checks whether the ray is within the bounds of the triangle, and I've been trying to get it to work via linear interpolation between the points with the value the bound calculations return as a t value. I haven't gotten it to work yet, but I'll let you know if it does.

Comment: You already have the intersection point (*with the plane*) in `ii`.  The subsequent code is to check if that point lies inside the triangle. If it does lie in the triangle then it is the point you want.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks! I tend to overcomplicate the simplest things sometimes.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli can you post it as an answer? So it can get accepted and help other people.